# Progressing through ArrayList strings on a JLabel

Tags: java, arraylist, jlabel

If I have a class, containing an ArrayList of questions for a quiz, how would I get a JLabel (contained in a seperate class) to progress through each question as its display, as each person answers a question correctly.

To clarify,

-JLabel displays first string from ArrayList
-Person answers question correctly
-JLabel then displays the second string in ArrayList

My ArrayList code is

```
import java.util.*;
public class Questions {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> SPOquestions = new ArrayList<String>(); // adding the     sports questions for the quiz

    SPOquestions.add("Who won the 2005 Formula One World Championship?");
    SPOquestions.add("Which team has the most Formula One Constructors titles?");
    SPOquestions.add("In what year did Roger Federer win his first 'Grand Slam'?");
    SPOquestions.add("How many 'Grand Slams' has Rafael Nadal won?");
    SPOquestions.add("Who has scored the most amount of goals in the Premier League?");
    SPOquestions.add("Who has won the most World Cups in football?");
    SPOquestions.add("How many MotoGP titles does Valentino Rossi hold?");
    SPOquestions.add("Who was the 2013 MotoGP champion?");
    SPOquestions.add("Who won the 2003 Rugby World Cup?");
    SPOquestions.add("In rugby league, how many points are awarded for a try?");
    SPOquestions.add("Who is the youngest ever snooker World Champion?");
    SPOquestions.add("In snooker, what is the highest maximum possible break?");
    SPOquestions.add("How many majors has Tiger Woods won?");
    SPOquestions.add("In golf, what is the tournament between the USA and Europe called?");
    SPOquestions.add("How many World Championships has darts player Phil Taylor won?");
    SPOquestions.add("What is the maximum possible amount of points a player can earn from throwing three darts?");
    SPOquestions.add("How many gold medals did Michael Phelps win at the 2008 Beijing Olympics?");
    SPOquestions.add("Who won the 2012 Olympic 100 metres mens race?");
    SPOquestions.add("Which of these events are not a part of the heptathlon?");
    SPOquestions.add("When was the first modern Olympics held?");


    ArrayList<String> MUSquestions = new ArrayList<String>(); // adding the music questions

    MUSquestions.add("'Slash' was a member of which US rock band?");
    MUSquestions.add("Brian May was a member of which English rock band?");
    MUSquestions.add("What is the name of the music festival held annually in the town of Boom, Belgium?");
    MUSquestions.add("The rapper Tupac Shakuer '2Pac' died in which year?");
    MUSquestions.add("Which of these bands headlined the 2013 Glastonbury music festival?");
    MUSquestions.add("Which of these people designed the 'Les Paul' series of guitars?");
    MUSquestions.add("Keith Moon was a drummer for which English rock band?");
    MUSquestions.add("Kanye West has a total of how many Grammy awards?");
    MUSquestions.add("Beyonce Knowles was formally a member of which US group?");
    MUSquestions.add("In which US city was rapper 'Biggie Smalls' born?");
    MUSquestions.add("Michael Jackson's first number one single in the UK as a solo artist was what?");
    MUSquestions.add("The best selling album of all time in the UK is what?");
    MUSquestions.add("The best selling album of all time in the US is what?");
    MUSquestions.add("What is the artist known as 'Tiesto's real name?");
    MUSquestions.add("Which of these was not a member of The Beatles?");

    ArrayList<String> GENquestions = new ArrayList<String>(); // adding general knowledge questions

    GENquestions.add("Who was the second President of the United States?");
    GENquestions.add("The youngest son of Bob Marley was who?");
    GENquestions.add("In the film '8 Mile', the character portrayed by Eminem is known as what?");
    GENquestions.add("What is the capital city of New Zealand?");
    GENquestions.add("What is the capital city of Australia?");
    GENquestions.add("How many millilitres are there in an English pint?");
    GENquestions.add("What was the biggest selling game for the PS2 worldwide?");
    GENquestions.add("What is the last letter of the Greek alphabet?");
    GENquestions.add("Who created the television series Futurama?");
    GENquestions.add("A word which reads the same backwards as it does forwards is known as a what?");
    GENquestions.add("A 'baker's dozen' consists of how many items?");
    GENquestions.add("World War 1 officially occured on which date?");
    GENquestions.add("'Trouble and strife' is cockney rhyming slang for what?");
    GENquestions.add("Who was the last Prime Minister to hail from the labour party in the UK?");
    GENquestions.add("WalMart is the parent company of which UK based supermarket chain?");




}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. Get that code out of a static main method where it is completely invisible to any other part of your program.
2. Instead create a non-static spoQuestions field of that class (note that variable names should begin with a lower-case letter), and give your class a getter method so that other classes can reach the ArrayList.
3. Better still, the text that you want to show is not really **code**, but rather it should be **data* and held in a text file. Move the Strings to a text file
4. And create code that will read the text in and fill your ArrayList with Strings from the file.
5. Then any class that wishes to use the list can access it. They will need to hold an int variable that represents the current index of the ArrayList, if they want to iterate through the list.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me as I am a little rusty. How should I program the code so it is invisible to everything else and also the subsequent getter method? ... i am aware of the fact that it should be in a text file and I was trying to implement this but initially couldn't, I shall try again hopefully with your guidance

Comment: @user3455584: You'll need to clarify your question a bit. I have no idea where/what you're stuck on.